# Rotating UIViewController Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I have the following code to display a UIViewController in horizontal orientation ontop of a UITableViewController.

```
  -(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [self.view addSubview:landscapeChartViewController.view];
    }

    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
        if(landscapeChartViewController != nil)
            [landscapeChartViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

**When the phone rotates, the view doesn't take up the entire screen.**

**The user is also able to scroll, thus showing the rest of the UITableViewController. I don't want the UITableViewController to be there in horizontal orientation.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `[self.view addSubview:landscapeChartViewController.view];`

Assuming you've set your frames correctly, this should be what you're looking for.

Comment: That is a start. My view appears but it doesn't take up the whole screen. When I rotate back in to portrait mode it is still in the view.

Comment: Taking up the whole screen involves setting the frame of the view...or replacing a view:

`self.view = landscapeChartViewController.view;`

Animate it if you wish. Also, in the rotation delegate, you can remove the subview (with the corresponding method) or change self.view back.

Answer (score 0):

`landscapeChartViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds`, perhaps?

Also keep in mind that the orientation change can happen "in the background" if you're using a tab bar controller, so you might also want to check the current orientation in `-viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: hmm that didn't seem to do it unfortunately. i am showing this view ontop of a UITableViewController, so when I scroll down I can see the rest of the tableview. I don't want that to happen.